# Select Validation Not Working ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

**My Select List Data : List of Strings**

```
public static class QuestionsSecretes
    {
        public static readonly IList<String> Liste_Questions_Secretes = new List<String>() {
                "Selectionner Une Question",
                "Quelle était la couleur de votre première voiture ?",
                "Quel est le nom de votre école primaire ?",
                "Quel est le nom de votre premier animal de compagnie ?",
                "Quel est votre plat préféré ?",
                "Quelle était la marque de votre première voiture ?" ,
                "Quel est le nom de jeune fille de votre mère ?",
                "Quel est le nom de votre commune de naissance ?",
            };

    }
```

***ViewModel : annotation attribute***

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Veuillez Selectionner votre Question Secrete ")]
        public string QuestionSecrete { get; set; }
```

i also tried this one :

```
 [StringLength(Int32.MaxValue, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Veuillez Selectionner votre Question Secrete")]
```

***My View : i set value of the first element to string.empty in order to fire the validaion , bu no chance ***

```
 <div class="inputs-block">
                                                 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 marg8">Question Secrete : </div> 
                                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
                                                        <label class="selct">
                                                        <select name="QuestionSecrete" id="QuestionSecrete">
                                                            <% foreach (var item in QuestionsSecretes.Liste_Questions_Secretes)
                                                               {%>
                                                             <%if (item.Equals(QuestionsSecretes.Liste_Questions_Secretes[0]))
                                                                      {%>
                                                                        <option value="<%: String.Empty %>"><%: item %></option>
                                                            <%}else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.QuestionSecrete) && Model.QuestionSecrete.Equals(item))
                                                                      {%>
                                                                        <option value="<%: item %>" selected="selected"><%: item %></option>
                                                            <%}else{ %>
                                                                   <option value="<%: item %>"><%: item %></option>
                                                               <%} %>
                                                            <%} %>
                                                        </select>
                                                        </label>
                                                       <div class="text-danger">
                                                            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.QuestionSecrete)%>
                                                         </div>
                                                    </div>



                                                </div>
```

i can't get the validation Message on select to work.
thnaks for your valuable time

Comment: You need to use the html helpers - `@Html.DropDownListFor()` or manually add all the appropriate `data-val` attributes used by client side validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are defining select manually. You can use the `Html.DropDownListFor` extension method to generate the select control.

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.QuestionSecrete, new  System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(Model.Liste_Questions_Secretes ), string.Empty, new {@class="form-control"})%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionSecrete)%>
```

Using above extension, rendered html shows a select control with a blank item. Also, validation will be fired if user does not choose any item in select while submitting a form.

The Model property is defined as

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Veuillez Selectionner votre Question Secrete ")]
public string QuestionSecrete { get; set; }
```

I have created [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rcjIDs) dotnet fiddle to demonstrate your example. You can run the fiddle to see the validation behavior.

Comment: thanks @user1672994 using the helper solved  the problem